# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client | Express & Firestore

Tags: firebase, express

```js
exports.addAdvert = async (req, res) => {
  try {
      const advert = req.body;
      const newAdvert = await db.collection("adverts").add({...advert,date: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()});
      const id = newAdvert.id;
    return res.status(200).json({ id });
  } catch (e) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: `Llamada fallida: ${e}` });
  }
};
```

Hi!! I'm developing a backend using express and Firebase. Actually done others calls to backend and firebase and works. I don't know when I call this one returns this error but in firebase creates the new advert.